# $state.go does not change url but redirect to that particular page

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to change my Url using $state.go but i am getting that page for which i have requested in $state.go , I have also used route.js

```js
angular.module("myApp")
    .controller('myController', ['$scope','$state',  function ($scope, $state) {
      $scope.showDetails = function(data){
                if(some true condition){
                  $state.go("create.preemp");
                  }
                else if(some true condition){
                  $state.go("create.prepolicy");
                }
            }
    }])


angular.module("myApp")
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('signin', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'signin/signin.html',
            controller: 'signinController'
          })
          .state('create.preemp', {
            url: '/create.preemp',
            templateUrl: 'preemp.html',
            controller: 'preempController'
           })
          .state('create.prepolicy', {
            url: '/create.prepolicy',
            templateUrl: 'prepolicy.html',
            controller: 'prepolicyController'
          })
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');   
    })
```

??

Comment: Try using prepolicy in place of create.preemp and see if it works.

Comment: but i have "create" as the parent one thats y ive use create.prepolicy